# Hangman - How to properly count the player wrong guesses?

Tags: c

Now my game correct counts up how many I have correct however it does not count up if the about of mismatched characters are equal to the length of the string. I've been trying to tinker with this code for a while any it still has yet to be able to be fixable. Here is my code:

```
/*includes and defines*/
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #define SIZE 50

     /*prototype definitions*/
     int compareString(char *, char *);

     int main(void){

        char word[SIZE];
        char input[SIZE];
        char guess[SIZE];
        int count = 0;
        int wrong = 0;
        int incorrect = 0;
        int right = 0;
        int len = 0;

        printf("Please enter the word you would like to have to guess.\nThen hand your computer over to the person you would like to have play:");
        fgets(word, SIZE, stdin);

        len = strlen(word);

        printf("Please guess one letter for the %d letter word!\n", len - 1);

        do{

            fgets(input, SIZE, stdin);

            for(count = 0; count < len - 1; count++){
                if(input[0] == word[count]){
                    printf("that letter is in the %d spot\n", count + 1);
                    ++right;
                }
                /*I know the problem lies here but i'm not sure how to fix it I've tried not using len-1         and just using len, I've tried not resetting the amount wrong. Everything!*/
                else if (input[0] != word[count]) {
                    ++wrong;
                        if(wrong == len - 1){
                            ++incorrect;
                        }
                    wrong = 0;
                }
            }

        }while(incorrect < 6 && right < len - 1);


        return 0;
     }
```

I know the problem lies here, the code setting the player mistakes. However I'm not sure how to fix it. I've tried not using len-1 and just using len, I've tried not resetting the amount wrong.

```
else if (input[0] != word[count]) {
                        ++wrong;
                            if(wrong == len - 1){
                                ++incorrect;
                            }
                        wrong = 0;
                    }
```

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: I'm not asking to write the code out for me. Just what is the code missing. If I didn't say it was for a class project then it would be fine? Doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I read the code so I see the comment there saying that you have an idea of where the problem is. Maybe you should also elaborate a bit more in the question itself. Honestly, I don't think it's a problem being a school project. I believe there's a problem when a person doesn't show enough effort in solving the problem before turning to SO. Another thing to consider is, not bringing the whole problem here but just the conceptual part. even when searching. don't look for hangman, look from string matching problems

Comment: This is my first post on here so I'm quite new to this whole set up.

Comment: @TheMadHouse how many times should you be able to get it wrong?

Comment: at least six. However I've tried to place a printf statement right after the if(wrong == len) to see where the error lies and it doesn't seem to ever reach that

Comment: Eventually once the incorrect counter is working I will get working on drawing a hang man. However I'm still developing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way you were trying to increase `incorrect`.
Just use `wrong` as a boolean that you will use to decide if you need to increase or not `incorrect`

Here's the solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 50

/*prototype definitions*/
int compareString(char *, char *);

int main(void){

  char word[SIZE];
  char input[SIZE];
  char guess[SIZE];
  int count = 0;
  int wrong = 1;
  int incorrect = 0;
  int right = 0;
  int len = 0;

  printf("Please enter the word you would like to have to guess.\nThen hand your computer over to the person you would like to have play:");
  fgets(word, SIZE, stdin);

  len = strlen(word);

  printf("Please guess one letter for the %d letter word!\n", len - 1);

  do{

    fgets(input, SIZE, stdin);
    wrong = 1;
    for(count = 0; count < len - 1; count++){

      if(input[0] == word[count]){
        printf("that letter is in the %d spot\n", count + 1);
        wrong = 0;
        ++right;
      }
      /*I know the problem lies here but i'm not sure how to fix it I've tried not using len-1         and just using len, I've tried not resetting the amount wrong. Everything!*/
    }
    if(wrong) {
      incorrect++;
    }

  }while(incorrect < 6 && right < len - 1);


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been at this program for hours now trying to fix it. Thanks for bearing with my noobness haha

Comment: Again I'm new to this, did that do the trick?

Comment: Yes it did :)
Upvote questions you like (using the arrow beside the question)
Upvote answers you like (again using the arrows)
and accept answers that answer your questions. That will take you far.
And as said before, try to think how to put your questions in a way that you don't seem to be just looking for an easy answer, try to show how much effort you did

Comment: Okay I will do in future questions. Thanks for showing me the ropes!